# Does creating an object directly in a vector, and then removing it from the vector, calls to a destructor?

Tags: c++

Say i have a class named `test`, and a vector

```
std::vector<test> Tests;
```

If i execute this code:

```
Tests.push_back(test());
```

and then

```
Tests.pop_back();
```

What happens to the test object? Is its destructor being called upon?

Comment: Try it. But, what would you expect? What are the implications of either variant?

Comment: Yes, the destructor is called and it's called even twice, since the temporary object passed to `push_back` is destroyed too... (Using `Tests.emplace_back();` would result in only a single invokation of the destructor.)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt jeez, i don't know what's wrong with me, that i didn't think of actually trying that. After trying it, it checks out with what fabian said. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example might show a little bit better what happens.

Live demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/c6-N-vyPc

---

Output will be :

```
Creating first vector (push_back)
>>>> Test constructor called
>>>> Test move constructor called
<<<< Test destructor called
Destroying first vector
<<<< Test destructor called

Creating second vector (emplace_back)
>>>> Test constructor called
Destroying second vector
<<<< Test destructor called
```

---

Example code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test
{
public:
    Test()
    {
        std::cout << ">>>> Test constructor called\n";
    }

    Test(const Test&)
    {
        std::cout << ">>>> Test copy constructor called\n";
    }

    Test(Test&&)
    {
        std::cout << ">>>> Test move constructor called\n";
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        std::cout << "<<<< Test destructor called\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    // scope to manage life cycle of vec1
    {
        std::cout << "\nCreating first vector (push_back)\n";
        std::vector<Test> vec1;
        vec1.push_back(Test{});
        std::cout << "Destroying first vector\n";
    }

    // scope to manage life cycle of vec2
    {
        std::cout << "\nCreating second vector (emplace_back)\n";
        std::vector<Test> vec2;
        vec2.emplace_back();
        std::cout << "Destroying second vector\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```